# Save a variable to environment till it is not erased

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am new to bash scripting, so if I ask anything stupid sorry for it xD

I'm making a script which run come cli commands everyday. The output which I get from the cli command is a ID which I have to use that same next day. So its like

```
cli-command-delete $oldid; # here we delete the old id which was generated past day

newid=$(cli-command-create) #here we get the new id.
```

Now I want to save the ***newid to oldid***, which will be used next day or next time when the script will run. How can I save it as a env variable & replace that value after new id is created? If vm reboots, will that value be saved?
I saw on google to use export, but I'm confused how to save it on other name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save it to some some permanent storage such as file and
read it when the script starts and ideally check if it could be
read. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

id_path=~/.id

oldid="$(cat $id_path)"

if [ -z "$oldid" ]
then
    printf "Failed to read oldid from %s\n" "$id_path" >&2
    exit 1
fi

cli-command-delete "$oldid"; # here we delete the old id which was generated past day

cli-command-create > "$id_path"
```

Comment: Thanks you very much I opted this method :)

Answer (score 1):

"If vm reboots, will that value be saved" -- No.

Write it to a file instead.

```bash
id_file=$HOME/.local/data/cli-command.id

# delete the old one
cli-command-delete "$(<"$id_file")"

# save the new one
cli-command-create > "$id_file"
```